# How to Resolve this issue "Could not find a stock quote for GOOGL or some other company names"

Tags: bots, skype, botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I am working on Bot technology, I have developed the stock bot to know stock prices of various companies using predefined channel in LUIS API of cognitive services.

https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/LUIS-api/documentation/Channels

For that I was deployed the above stock channel JSON data into my LUIS Account, it creates the LUIS application successfully, Next I was published my LUIS application.

After that I checked with my query, then it gives JSON response correctly like this below.

```
{
"query": "what is the current stock price of MSFT",
"topScoringIntent": {
"intent": "GetCurrentPrice",
"score": 0.997907,
"actions": [
  {
    "triggered": true,
    "name": "GetCurrentPrice",
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "Symbol",
        "type": "Company",
        "required": true,
        "value": [
          {
            "entity": "msft",
            "type": "Company",
            "resolution": {}
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

},

But once I added my bot into skype channel and then I was entered the text like “what was the stock price at closing time for google”, it always gives results like this “Could not find a stock quote for GOOGL.”

Can you please tell me where I did mistake in my LUIS application or tell me how to resolve the above issue.

I think there may be issue in Stock Channel API, is it correct?

Comment: Can you post some of the code of your bot?

Comment: I didn't write any code in my bot, just configured LUIS application with Predefined stock channel and then gave the LUIS Endpoint to my Bot Messaging EndPoint.

Comment: You can also check this: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/Stock_Bot

Comment: I don't want to use Custom API's like yahoo finance API, I want to use LUIS API predefined stock Channel API to get  stock prices of various companies.

Answer (score 0):

Try the ticker symbol 'goog'.  You can also add the list of ticker symbols into the Phrase List Features so they are all treated the same as far as executing the intent.

Comment: Thanks, I added the symbols(goog, amzn etc...) into Phrase List Feature but also  got the same warning in my bot like "Could not find a stock quote for GOOGL."